# SwiftUI UICollectionView or UITableView wrapper and reusable cells is it efficient to replace cell content with new SwitUI views

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swiftui

As we know when using **UITableView** or **UICollectionView** we register **reusable cell** classes and then we **dequeue this reusable cells** to make list/collection working more efficiently with large dataset.

Is it possible to use such UITableViews or UICollectionViews with SwiftUI Content in any approach in such way to **not deteriorate efficiency** of this lists/collections?

I consider such examples:

1. UICollectionView cells

   ```
   private func cellProvider(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell? {

       print("Providing cell for \(indexPath)")

       guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView> else {
           fatalError("Coult not load cell!")
       }

       cell.host(content(indexPath, item))

       return cell
   }
   ```

   class HostingControllerCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

   ```
   weak var controller: UIHostingController<Content>?

   func host(_ view: Content, parent: UIViewController? = nil) {

       if let controller = controller {
           controller.rootView = view
           controller.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       } else {
           let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
           self.controller = controller
           controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear

           layoutIfNeeded()

           parent?.addChild(controller)
           contentView.addSubview(controller.view)
           controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor),
               controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor),
               controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor),
               controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor)
           ])

           if let parent = parent {
               controller.didMove(toParent: parent)
           }
           controller.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. UITableViewCell

   class HostingTableViewControllerCell: UITableViewCell {

   ```
   private weak var controller: UIHostingController<Content>?

   func host(_ view: Content, parent: UIViewController) {
       if let controller = controller {
           controller.rootView = view
           controller.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       } else {
           let swiftUICellViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
           controller = swiftUICellViewController
           swiftUICellViewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear

           layoutIfNeeded()

           parent.addChild(swiftUICellViewController)
           contentView.addSubview(swiftUICellViewController.view)
           swiftUICellViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: swiftUICellViewController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
           contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: swiftUICellViewController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
           contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: swiftUICellViewController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
           contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: swiftUICellViewController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

           swiftUICellViewController.didMove(toParent: parent)
           swiftUICellViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
   }
   ```

   }

or I have other solutions just with replacing subviews of contentView

```
class HostingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    func host<Content: View>(rootView: Content) {

        self.contentView.subviews.forEach {  $0.removeFromSuperview() }

        let view = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView).view
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.contentView.addSubview(view!)

        view!.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
        view!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            view!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            view!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            view!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])

    }
}
```

Maybe should I register multiple HostingCells with specific view type 
and instead of replacing entire view try to somehow setTitle() setImage() on this SwiftUI content views.

```
 private func cellProvider(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell? {

        print("Providing cell for \(indexPath)")
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<CustomView>.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<CustomView> else {
            fatalError("Could not load cell!")
        }

        if cell.hostingController == nil {
            cell.host(Text("LOL"))
        } else { 
           cell.hostingController.rootView 
           cell.controller?.rootView?.setTitle("Text") 
        } 

        return cell
}

struct CustomView: View { 

   @State var text: String 

   func setTitle(_ text: String) { self.text = text } 
}
```

But here question. How I could register multiple SwiftUI content views like CustomView1, CustomView2, CustomView3?

maybe at constraction time of add

```
CollectionView(reusableCells: [CustomView1.self, CustomView2.self],...)
```

and then in configureCollectionView() add

collectionView.register(HostingControllerCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomViewX.reuseIdentifier)

but is this last suggested approach better and how I could pass View struct types and store then off different view type without not erasing type to AnyView

UPDATE

If I added to current soluton 100k items then app works very very slows, views are not layout properly and it seems to crash very frequently. So it seems that cells aren't reused properly.

```
static func generateCategories() -> [Item] {

        var items = [Item]()

        for i in 0..<100000 {
            items.append(.category(category: Category(id: "\(i)", title: "Category \(i)")) )
        }

        return items
    }
```

Comment: Here is my gist with full example: 
https://gist.github.com/michzio/461a63280841bbddb1dcfebe8f1da24b

Comment: I had a look at your gist, but the generic cell type is missing from it : HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.   I would think that 100k items is a fairly tough test. It would be interesting to try this to see if it has improved in the latest iOS release.

Comment: At the end this CollectionView as I remember works very well with thousands of cells
You can try this https://medium.com/@michaziobro_21492/uicollectionview-in-swiftui-reusable-component-with-uicollectionviewcompositionallayout-and-a26d4b64dd94

There is also github sample project as I remember